# Accessors (Properties) without Form.ShowDialog()

Tags: c#

I am trying to set a *ConstantLine* for a *DevExpress* *SplineChart* that is created in the `Form1` from `Form2` and also set a `numericalupdown.value` placed in the `Form2` for a `textBox.text` that is placed in the `Form1`, whilst both `Form1` and `Form2` are Open and running.

I am using from accessors `{get;set;}` to get and set values of *DevExpressChart* as i have written down in my codes.

I can get the values, but i can't set any value without using `Form1.ShowDialog()`.

I have also used `Form1.Update();` and`Form1.Refresh();` but the mentioned code only run successfully with the use of `Form1.Show();` or `Form1.ShowDialog();`

However, i want them to execute while both forms are running `Form2` as a child of `Form1` an seeing the changes in the `Form1`

**Code**

```
//Code Snippet in the Form2:
//NumericalUpDown-ValueChanged Event: In Form2

private void numUpDnShkgTimeRstcConfig_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

    if (chkBxShakingTimeRestCteLineConfig.Checked == true)
    {
        XYDiagram diagram = (XYDiagram)Frm1.SplineChart.Diagram;
        diagram.AxisX.ConstantLines.Add(new ConstantLine("Shaking Time", Convert.ToString(numUpDnShkgTimeRstcConfig.Value)));
        Frm1.TxtBx = Convert.ToString(numUpDnShkgTimeRstcConfig.Value);
    } 
}

//Code Snippet in the  Form1
//Pass Objects And Parameter.

public DevExpress.XtraCharts.ChartControl SplineChart
{
    get {return SplineChrt1Form1; }
    set { SplineChrt1MainFrm = value; }
}

public string TxtBx
{
    get { return txtBxSmplWt1Form1.Text; }
    set { txtBxSmplWt1Form1.Text = value; }
}

...
```

Comment: i want to do changes in the Form1 that already opened, and i don't want to close and open or duplicate it.

Comment: Can you add the code, from Form2, that you use to create and show Form1 the first time please?

Comment: i am opening Form1 from a radial-menu and  Form2 will open with a button click event that placed in the Form1. Form2 is using to configure something like Constant-line position of a devexpress splineChart that is placed in the Form1 and form2 will open with: Form2 frm2=new Form2(); then: frm2.Show();

Comment: `Form1 frm1 = new Form1();` Creates a new instance of `Form1`. If you want to work with the open instance of `Form1` not a new instance, then you should pass that instance to `Form2` or use `var frm1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understood your problem was that:

1. You are displaying a Chart in Form1.
2. From Form1, you want to show a second form (Form2) that allows you to change or specify values for the Chart in Form1.
3. You want to get the updated values from Form2 in to Form1.

The best way to setup this sort of notification and updating of a parent form from a child form is to use [`Events`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/). Events enable a child form to notify its parent without actually knowing anything about the parent.

**Step 1 - Create an EventArgs class.** This class will be used to hold the information you want to pass from Form2 to Form1.

Generally speaking, I find it is better to have the properties as Read Only and only set them in the constructor for this sort of event.

```
// I wasn't sure what the parameters were called or their type,
// so I just used an int and string to demonstrate the functionality
public class ChartValuesChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ChartValuesChangedEventArgs (int value1, string value2)
    {
        Value1 = value1;
        Value2 = value2;
    }

    public int Value1 { get; private set; }
    public string Value2 { get; private set; }
}
```

**Step 2 - Declare the event that will be raised from Form2.** This is what will notify the Parent (Form1) that the values have changed and what the values are.

```
public event EventHandler<ChartValuesChangedEventArgs> ValuesChanged;
```

**Step 3 - Raise the Event.** This is where you notify the Parent that the values have changed.
For this example, I am raising the event on a Button Click. You can just as easily put the content of this function in your own `numUpDnShkgTimeRstcConfig_ValueChanged` function.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChartValuesChangedEventArgs chartValuesChangedEventArgs = new
        ChartValuesChangedEventArgs(numUpDnShkgTimeRstcConfig.Value,
                                    txtBxSmplWt1Form1.Text);
    OnValuesChanged(chartValuesChangedEventArgs);
}

protected virtual void OnValuesChanged(ChartValuesChangedEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler<ChartValuesChangedEventArgs> handler = ValuesChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

**Step 4 - Handle the event.** This is where you update your chart with the new/updated values from Form2

```
private void ShowForm2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ValuesChanged += form2_ValuesChanged;
    form2.Show();
}

void form2_ValuesChanged(object sender, ChartValuesChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Update the chart values here
    Debug.Print(e.Value1.ToString());
    Debug.Print(e.Value2);
}
```

Comment: thanks a million for the time that you gave me to answer my question. i exactly want to do the same thing that you are mentioned above. but i don't want to use from Show(); or ShowDialog(); and i want to do it whilst both forms are open. form1 and form2 are running and visible. as i understood, the 1st and 4th parts must be written in the form1, and the 2nd and 3rd parts must be written in the form2. is that right?

Comment: @Ehsan I think there is a little confusion here, Step 1 is a new separate class. Step 4 is for the one and only time that you show your Form2. You said that Form2 is shown from Form1, in that function add the line `form2.ValuesChanged += form2_ValuesChanged;` and the rest of Step 4. You are correct for Steps 2 and 3.

Comment: @Ehsan I changed the ShowDialog() to a Show(). It makes no difference to this functionality, but does change how your app behaves. Use .Show() and everything will be fine

Comment: i must to make the step one (new class) in the form2? if so, if i get my values and assign a numericalupdown.value or a textbox.text to them, i will face with the field initializer error.

Comment: @Ehsan The class `ChartValuesChangedEventArgs` sits in its own file, alongside the other class files that you have. It should be public and available throughout your entire solution

Comment: Please correct if i am doing wrong. i have made a class as you said, then i have written public event EventHandler<ClassName> ValuesChanged; in the Form2; then step3 with these changes{ ClassName classname = new ClassName();
   classname.MethodName(1,"abc"); because i encountered with error in step3, and i have written the rest of the Step3 in a numericalupdown_valuechanged Event. and all of the step4 into the button_Click event which make the Form2 show.

Comment: void form2_ValuesChanged(object sender, ClassName e) gives an error (scope error from sender). excuse me to take your time.

Comment: @Ehsan Can I suggest that you start again with trying to implement my suggestion? Making changes to the classes and their functionality when you don't yet understand what they are doing is not going to help you.

Comment: Thanks a million.excuse me to take your time.

Comment: Hi JayV Thanks a lot for your answer. I studied many papers to learn what you did.your answer was the best way that I saw. I like to be sure if you receive my appreciation.