# How to update text in the label in another form in VB.NET when both form are active (Message Passing) [Visual Studio 2010]

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, message-passing

I have created two forms say Form1 and Form2. Form1 consists of a label and a button which shows Form2. Now Form2 contains a text box and a button. When the button in Form2 is clicked, the content in textbox should be shown to the label in Form1. This can be repeated as long as user want.
Until now I can pass data to unopened Form. But I can not update the data, when both forms are active.

In Form1, I have declared a global string

```
Public Property message As String
```

In Form2 the button click event is as follow

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim obj As New Form1
    obj.message = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Even I have tried

```
obj.label1.Text = TextBox1.Text
```

But these were not successful.
Please help to achieve the target.
Please remeber I want to achieve this using two normal Forms not any special type of Forms like MDI.

Comment: Take a read of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50868898/accessors-properties-without-form-showdialog/50873382#50873382). It shows how to use Events to De-Couple the link between forms. It is in C# though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a reference to Form1 into Form2 via the `Show()` method.  This reference can be retrieved in Form2 using the `.Owner` property.

In Form1:

```
Dim f2 As New Form2()
f2.Show(Me) ' <-- passing reference to Form1 into Form2
```

In Form2:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f1 As Form1 = DirectCast(Me.Owner, Form1)
    f1.message = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```